# where is the error in this oiplayer fallback function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When trying to use [oiplayer](https://github.com/elfuego/oiplayer) 
I get an error when this fallback function is called:

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
    // i tried adding this: header("content-type:application/json");

    $('div.player').oiplayer(
    server: 'http://www.openimages.eu', 
    jar: '/oiplayer/plugins/cortado-ovt-stripped-0.6.0.jar',
    flash: '/oiplayer/plugins/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf', 
    controls: 'top'
    );
});
```

Firefox says: SyntaxError: missing **)** after argument list 
Chrome says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token **:** 
Safari says: Unexpected token **)**  and points to the line that first has an **:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugins/flowplayer-3.2.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"><!-- help ie --></script>
<script src="js/jquery.oiplayer.js" type="text/javascript"><!-- help ie --></script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="build/oiplayergo.js">
</script>

        <div id="container" style ="position:absolute; left:20%;top:25%;">
        <!--img class="preview video" width="788" height="288" title="click to play" alt="click to play" src="http://www.openimages.eu/images/599192/WEEKNUMMER364-HRE0000D9C6.png" 
        style = "position:absolute; left:0;right:0;"></img-->
        <div class="player" style = "position:absolute; left:0;right:0;>
        <video width="788" height="288">
          <source type="video/ogg; codecs=theora" src="http://www.openimages.eu/files/09/9734.9730.WEEKNUMMER364-HRE0000D9C6.ogv"  />
          <source type="video/webm; codecs=vp8" src="http://www.openbeelden.nl/files/09/88068.9730.WEEKNUMMER364-HRE0000D9C6.webm" />
          <source type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2" src="http://www.openimages.eu/files/09/9740.9730.WEEKNUMMER364-HRE0000D9C6.mp4" />
        </video>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the options should be an object, you have incorrect syntax anyways.

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
    $('div.player').oiplayer({ //<-- Here
    server: 'http://www.openimages.eu', 
    jar: '/oiplayer/plugins/cortado-ovt-stripped-0.6.0.jar',
    flash: '/oiplayer/plugins/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf', 
    controls: 'top'
    });//<-- Here
});
```

It seems like the documentation in the link provided is also has similar usage which is incorrect, settings should be an object, so try the above.

This is what is defaulted according to the source:

```
jQuery.fn.oiplayer = function(settings) {
    var config = {
        server : 'http://www.openimages.eu',
        jar : '/oiplayer/plugins/cortado-ovt-stripped-0.6.0.jar',
        flash : '/oiplayer/plugins/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf',
        controls : true,
        log: 'error'
    };
    if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);
```

Comment: hmm. fixing this syntax fixes the error, but then it tells me:
`TypeError: $(...).oiplayer is not a function`
And the syntax i had is what the documentation says.

Comment: oh you just saw it too. i will try what you have suggested now

Comment: @jsky that definitely is incorrect, the one in the documentation, It has to be an object. Try if you can put together a fiddle if the issue persists.

Comment: ok thanks for your help sofar. i will get back to this this arvo, as i have to help my dad with something now.

Comment: I fixed the syntax as you suggested and errors are gone now. I removed other javascript that could be conflicting, updated jquery but still no video showing. was hoping this would work out of the box, gonna look at video.js or another solution.